# Why am I getting blocked by CORS policy error when sending cookies from Java backend to React?

Tags: reactjs, spring, web-applications, cors

I am writing web service for my project at university. We need to use jwt tokens and store them in httponly cookie. When I make login request i get this error. Can you help, please? And how can i add https protocol to react adding https=true in packege.json doesnt work. I am using Windows.

Acess to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://localhost/user/login' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' header in the response is '' which must be 'true' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.

Java -port 443

```
@CrossOrigin(allowCredentials = "true",origins = "http://localhost:3000")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class UserController {

@PostMapping("/signup")
    private UserDto signUp(@RequestBody UserDetailsDto userDetailsDto) {
        return userService.signUp(userDetailsDto);
    }

}
```

```
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

 @Override
    public ResponseEntity<String> logIn(UserDto userDto) {
        if(userRepository.findByLogin(userDto.login()) == null)
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED).body("Podano niepoprawne dane");

        boolean isSuccess = passwordEncoder.validatePassword(
                userDto.password(), userRepository.findByLogin(userDto.login()).getPassword());

        if (isSuccess) {
            LocalDateTime expirationDateTime = LocalDateTime.now().plusMinutes(5);
            String token =  jwtService.generateJws(userDto.login());
            long expirationTimestamp = expirationDateTime.toEpochSecond(ZoneOffset.UTC);

            HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
            headers.add(HttpHeaders.SET_COOKIE, "token=" + token + "; Path=/; Expires=" + expirationTimestamp + ";HttpOnly");
            return ResponseEntity.ok().headers(headers).body("Zalogowano pomyślnie");
        }

        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED).body("Podano niepoprawne dane");
    }
}
```

React - port 3000

```
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;

class UserService{

        saveUser(user){
            return axios.post(USER_API_BSE_URL+'/signup' ,user);
        }
}

export default new UserService();
```

I tried activating credentials and creating proxy but i dont know how to do it properly.

Comment: Try allowing request-header name `Content-Type` in your CORS configuration (on your server).